# Jet engine (Access) : Passing a list of values to a stored procedure

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, jet

I am currently writing a VBA-based Excel add-in that's heavily based on a Jet database backend (I use the Office 2003 suite -- the problem would be the same with a more recent version of Office anyway).

During the initialization of my app, I create stored procedures that are defined in a text file. Those procedures are called by my app when needed.

Let me take a simple example to describe my issue: suppose that my app allows end-users to select the identifiers of orders for which they'd like details. Here's the table definition:

> Table tblOrders: OrderID LONG, OrderDate DATE, (other fields)

The end-user may select one or more OrderIDs, displayed in a form - s/he just has to tick the checkbox of the relevant OrderIDs for which s/he'd like details (OrderDate, etc).

Because I don't know in advance how many OrderID s/he will select, I could dynamically create the SQL query in the VBA code by cascading WHERE clauses based on the choices made on the form:

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE OrderID = 1 OR OrderID = 2 OR OrderID = 3
```

or, much simpler, by using the IN keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE OrderID IN (1,2,3)
```

Now if I turn this simple query into a stored procedure so that I can dynamically pass list of OrderIDs I want to be displayed, how should I do? I already tried things like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest (@OrderList varchar) AS
  SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE OrderID IN (@OrderList)
```

But this does not work (I was expecting that), because `@OrderList` is interpreted as a string (e.g. "1,2,3") and not as a list of long values. (I adapted from code found here: [Passing a list/array to SQL Server stored procedure](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm))

I'd like to avoid dealing with this issue via pure VBA code (i.e. dynamically assigning list of values to a query that is hardcoded in my application) as much as possible. I'd understand if ever this is not possible.

Any clue?

Comment: Just an additional precision: I already looked at threads such as "Passing an array of ID's to a stored procedure" and explications given here :"http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html", but those apply to SQL Server only.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the query-statement string dynamically. In SQL Server you can have a function whose return value is a TABLE, and invoke that function inline as if it were a table. Or in JET you could also create a kludge -- a temporary table (or persistent table that serves the function of a temporary table) that contains the values in your in-list, one per row, and join on that table.  The query would thus be a two-step process: 1) populate temp table with INLIST values, then  2) execute the query joining on the temp table.

```
       MYTEMPTABLE
       autoincrementing id
       QueryID  [some value to identify the current query, perhaps a GUID]
       myvalue  one of the values in your in-list, string


      select * from foo
      inner join MYTEMPTABLE on foo.column = MYTEMPTABLE.myvalue and MYTEMPTABLE.QueryId = ?

      [cannot recall if JET allows ANDs in INNER JOIN as SQL Server does -- 
      if not, adjust syntax accordingly]
```

instead of

```
      select * from foo where foo.column IN (... )
```

In this way you could have the same table handle multiple queries concurrently, because each query would have a unique identifier. You could delete the in-list rows after you're finished with them:

```
      DELETE FROM MYTEMPTABLE where QueryID = ?
```

P.S. There would be several ways of handling data type issues for the join. You could cast the string value in MYTEMPTABLE as required, or you could have multiple columns in MYTEMPTABLE of varying datatypes, inserting into and joining on the correct column:

```
       MYTEMPTABLE
       id
       queryid
       mytextvalue
       myintvalue
       mymoneyvalue
       etc
```